# Metadata Information( Hotspot point information ) in png image using java

Tags: java

Please let me know how we can add or save hotspot point information in a png image using java.

I want to retrieve this information at the time on clicking on image at specified hotspot point.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Kaveesh

Comment: Extremely unclear what you're asking for here. Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

The PNG format does not provide a default way to mapping image areas to strings.

Hence you will need to figure out a place to put the mapping information in the first place.  That decision will then determine how you will use it.

I believe that PNG allows for comment strings.  You could determine a way to encode the information you need in comment strings, but you will need to do all the work yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help,I will map my information in string..but how can i store that string in comment tag of png image using java .Please elaborate more...and is there any java api to store some information in comment tag.